# How can I configure site Authorization for an MVC site with Web Forms components?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, authorization, forms-authentication, webforms

I have an MVC site where I need to use the ReportViewer control to integrate with SSRS. This means I need to have a Web Forms page within the site specifically for dealing with reports. Thankfully this is fairly painless. However, the way my authentication/authorization is managed creates a bit of an issue.

Currently, I have a global filter applying the `AuthorizeAttribute` to all controllers. I have then decorated the appropriate methods on the Login controller with the `AllowAnonymous` attribute

This does not affect the Web Forms page though meaning that anonymous users can navigate directly to it.

Within the web.config I have tried the following:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login/index" defaultUrl="home/index"/>
    </authentication>

    ...etc...
</system.web>
```

However, this then takes precedence over the `AllowAnonymous` attribute applied on the login methods within MVC, so you are continually redirected to the back to the login page.

Changing the configuration to use a `location` tag as below works fine.

```
<location path="Reports.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<system.web>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login/index" defaultUrl="home/index"/>
  </authentication>

  ...etc...
</system.web>
```

Is this the correct method to use or can I avoid having 2 separate locations for managing the authorization settings?

Comment: Are you using a sitemap?

Comment: No we're not using a sitemap.